# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '= '15' OFFSET = '0''

Tags: php, mysql

Getting error after changing from `PHP` to `PDO`. Previously I used following code to select from `database` after changing from `PHP` to `PDO` I receive following error can some one help me to sort error

`PHP`

```
$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

$sql = "SELECT countries_name FROM countries WHERE 1 ORDER BY countries_name ASC LIMIT $limit OFFSET $offset";
try {
  $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute();
  $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
  echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
  foreach ($results as $res) {
    echo '<h3>' . $res['countries_name'] . '</h3>';
  }
}
```

**PDO**

```
$limit = (intval($_GET['limit']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['limit'] : 10;
$offset = (intval($_GET['offset']) != 0 ) ? $_GET['offset'] : 0;

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT countries_name FROM countries ORDER BY countries_id ASC LIMIT = :limit OFFSET = :offset");
    $stmt->bindParam(':limit', $limit);
    $stmt->bindParam(':offset', $offset);
    $stmt->execute();
    $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
} catch (Exception $ex) {
    echo $ex->getMessage();
}
if (count($results) > 0) {
    foreach ($results as $res) {
        echo '<h3>' . $res['countries_name'] . '</h3>';
    }
}
```

Comment: `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` do not use equality to assign the value. It's `...LIMIT 1 OFFSET 3` (for example). Have a look at the manual https://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/select.html

Comment: As the error says you have a syntax error in that spot. Why did you add the equal signs? Also always post the exact and full error message in the question

Comment: i also tried `SELECT countries_name FROM countries ORDER BY countries_id ASC :limit :offset` but didn't work

Comment: @Iam None of the comments suggested that syntax, which also won't work.

Comment: ```LIMIT :offset,:limit``` should be the correct syntax

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen so how do i solve this

Comment: @SloanThrasher can you place full syntax

Comment: Your Query should be 
"SELECT countries_name FROM countries ORDER BY countries_id ASC LIMIT $offset, $limit"